# How to bind external button/joystick to GPIO and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a checkers game and using buttons and a joystick for movement and selection of pieces. When I try to use the following code my buttons and joystick input work, but I am getting duplicates of them. Take the arbitrary right() method. If I press right on my joystick my program prints "right" twice instead of just once or in the game it would move two spaces instead of just once.

```
buttons = [6,17]
leds= [5,16]
joystick = [18,19,20,21]

def joystickEvent(window, joystick):
    window.event_generate('<<joystick{}>>'.format(joystick))
        
def button1Event(window,button):
    window.event_generate('<<button{}>>'.format(button))

def right(event):
    print("right")

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
for i in range(len(joystick)):
    GPIO.setup(joystick[i], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(joystick[0], GPIO.BOTH, callback=lambda x:joystickEvent(window,joystick[0]))
GPIO.add_event_detect(joystick[1], GPIO.BOTH, callback=lambda x:joystickEvent(window,joystick[1]))
GPIO.add_event_detect(joystick[2], GPIO.BOTH, callback=lambda x:joystickEvent(window,joystick[2]))
GPIO.add_event_detect(joystick[3], GPIO.BOTH, callback=lambda x:joystickEvent(window,joystick[3]))

for i in range(len(buttons)):
    GPIO.setup(buttons[i],GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
    GPIO.setup(leds[i],GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.add_event_detect(buttons[0], GPIO.BOTH, callback= lambda x:button1Event(window,buttons[0]))
GPIO.add_event_detect(buttons[1], GPIO.BOTH, callback= lambda x:button1Event(window,buttons[1]))

    
window.bind("<<joystick18>>",right)
window.bind("<<joystick19>>",left)
window.bind("<<joystick20>>",up)
window.bind("<<joystick21>>",down)
window.bind("<<button6>>",button1)
window.bind("<<button17>>",button2)
```

Comment: Should `GPIO.RISING` or `GPIO.FALLING` be used instead of `GPIO.BOTH` in `GPIO.add_event_detect()`?

Comment: Sorry I should have added that, I tried switching between RISING/FALLING/BOTH but they all gave me the same result.

Comment: Then you may try different values for the `bouncetime` option of `add_event_detect()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what was missing. I set `bouncetime` to 800 and everything works smoothly now.